# Maybe it crashed because of afnetworking

Tags: ios, crash, afnetworking

My application crashed again, this time exporting the device crash log as follows (mind articles 11 and 12):

I tried to symbolic it, but I didn't know how to get the dSYM files from afnetworking from the project.

```
Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x2803df960 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000197cccda8 nanov2_allocate_from_block$VARIANT$armv81 + 528
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000197cccda8 nanov2_allocate_from_block$VARIANT$armv81 + 528
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000197ccc040 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$armv81 + 140
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000197ccbf64 nanov2_malloc$VARIANT$armv81 + 60
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x0000000197cd99a0 malloc_zone_malloc + 156
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019808e160 _CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 324
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019802b970 __CFArrayInit + 224
7   Foundation                      0x0000000198b75470 NSKVOCopyPendingNotificationStack + 152
8   Foundation                      0x0000000198b720f8 NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications.llvm.16432713543580414412 + 364
9   Foundation                      0x0000000198ae8ad4 -[NSProgress _setValueForKeys:settingBlock:] + 272
10  Foundation                      0x0000000198aeb9dc -[NSProgress setCompletedUnitCount:] + 132
11  AFNetworking                    0x00000001051c965c 0x10519c000 + 185948
12  AFNetworking                    0x00000001051d1a18 0x10519c000 + 219672
13  CFNetwork                       0x0000000198898b94 __67-[NSURLSession delegate_dataTask:didReceiveData:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.303 + 36
14  Foundation                      0x0000000198b8c8bc __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
15  Foundation                      0x0000000198a94ab8 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
16  Foundation                      0x0000000198a93f8c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740
17  Foundation                      0x0000000198b8e790 __NSOQSchedule_f + 272
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b356c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b36484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b0ce04 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 404
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b0c4e8 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 592
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b18aec _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 344
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b1934c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197d1917c _pthread_wqthread + 472
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197d1bcec start_wqthread + 4
```

If it's not afnetworking fault, can anyone see why? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

So, your app has crashed pretty deep in Apple's code, and specifically inside libsystem_malloc. While I cannot be **certain**, my guess is you're looking at an example of heap corruption.

Dynamically allocated memory is shared by your entire process, and everything in it. That means that any code could potentially overwrite and/or otherwise corrupt structures used by other, even unrelated, parts of the system. In this case, it looks like something has messed up the internal book-keeping structures used by malloc. I would guess this happens by overrunning a buffer and writing outside of an allocated piece of memory's bounds.

What I can say with high confidence is that this particular report does not give you enough information to blame AFNetworking. It just happened to be unlucky enough to be running when that corrupt memory was accessed. Even one memory corruption bug can cause a variety of different crashes. Because of that, it's not really possible to reason about the cause of any one particular crash.

The good news is this kind of thing is very common. Bad news is it can be very hard to track down. What I'd recommend trying is to make use of the memory debugging tools that Apple provides. Things like NSZombies (via instruments), guardmalloc, and malloc scribble. Your best bet is to just fix all the memory-related bugs you can find.